# Detecting c++ structure is updated from unit test

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I have a family of data structures, that should be passed from one layer to over using boost::serialization.
For example

```
struct DataType1
{
    std::string field1;
    std::string field2;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & field1;
        ar & field2;
    }
};
```

I want to write unit test's on this, just to be sure that i did no miss some fields (there are a lot of structures and fields).

The problem is, if I add new field in structure (i will definitely do) and forget to update unit test, this field will not covered by unit test.

My question is: how to detect that structure (or class) is changed. 
My idea was to use static_assert(sizeof(DataType1) == HARD_CODED_VALUE) but it suffers from difference in structure size in different compilers, platforms (x64, x86) and configurations (release, debug).

Any good idea how to handle this?

Comment: You'd have to remember to update the HARD_CODED_VALUE as well, so that doesn't solve the problem!  Ultimately, unless you're autogenerating your code and unit test, there is no automated way to keep them synchronised.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That would at least fail in compilation. I guess OP is just concerned with runtime bugs.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is, if I add new field in structure (i will definitely do) and forget to update unit test, this field will not covered by unit test.
>
> My question is: how to detect that structure (or class) is changed.
>
> My idea was to use static_assert(sizeof(DataType1) == HARD_CODED_VALUE) [...]

That is not a portable solution (as you yourself noted).

> Any good idea how to handle this?

Yes: can you start with updating the test?

That is, do not decide what should go in the structure, then add it, then update tests (if you do not forget).

Instead, update tests to check for the new serialized data, **then make sure the updated tests fail**, and only then update the code so the tests pass.

This approach (write/update unit tests first) has been created (partly) to tackle exactly this problem.

The test-first approach has other advantages as well:

- it neatly avoids [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)
- it minimizes premature optimization
- it evolves naturally for tracking the feature-completeness of your application/implementation.

Comment: I really like your proposal but unfortunately can't mark it as answer. I work in team, and I will have difficulties to persuade every team member to write tests before actual code. Our team practices unit testing, but not so fanatical about TDD.

Comment: I don't do TDD myself. All I am saying is that when you have to make a code change (and already have a test for it) it is much more organized to start the change by updating the test (because when you want a change you're already clear how the new way of behaving should be before you start changing the code).

Answer (score 2):

Add a comment to the class definition to remind you that you have to tweak the serializer when adding members. There are limits on what a computer could do for you -- that's why code review is important. Let any patches be reviewed by another programmer, have a rigorous set of test cases and hope for the best.

I'm sure you could e.g. write a clang plugin which will make sure that a particular method references every member of a struct, but do you really *need* this and can you invest your time into that?

That said, you have bonus points for trying to offload as much work to the computer as possible. Even the `static_assert` trick is a good one. If you protect it with a set of `#ifdef`s for one particular ABI and architecture where you build often enough, it might do a great job.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
// DataType1_members.h

FIELD_DEF(std::string, field1);
FIELD_DEF(std::string, field2);

// DataType1.h

struct DataType1
{
#define FIELD_DEF(type, name) type name
    #include "DataType1_members.h"
#undef FIELD_DEF

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
#define FIELD_DEF(type, name) ar & name
    #include "DataType1_members.h"
#undef FIELD_DEF
    }
};
```

That way you only need to add fields in one place.

Comment: Reasons I don't like this (sorry): it's obscure, it uses  multiple header files to define the interface of a struct, the interface is not explicit and it uses macros to generate code (the code you see is different than the code your compiler and debugger see).

Comment: @utnapistim: This "pattern" is actually relatively well-known, at least in C; see [*X macro*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro).  As C++ doesn't have reflection, this is pretty much the only way to DRY for things like serialization (AFAIK).

Comment: I know :(. I saw it explained by Stephan T. Lavavej in his series about advanced STL. It's an interesting precompiler trick and the only place I think it's acceptable to use, is in _already stable_ library code (code that won't change, will never be debugged and is already tested) - because in code that you expect to keep changing, it tends to become a maintenance nightmare (for the reasons in my comment above). Writing your development/unstable code like this can waste more time in maintenance.

Comment: @utnapistim - I agree that it's not the prettiest code, but I don't think it's that difficult to maintain. You can do it in a single header. See the 'external links' section in the wiki page Oli linked to (specifically - http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/the-x-macro/228700289). And if you place it right above the data structure declaration, it won't be difficult to find the fields, and with a semi-competent auto-complete it doesn't even matter.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I found my solution in using boost::fusion.
Here you can iterate over all members of your struct. So there is no need to do any more manually.
As well you get the nice feature of compile time introspection as well. So it is easy to print the content of the complete struct eg. into a log file by a liitle template code.

Answer (score 0):

In your unit tests, you could do a static_assert check with expected struc size :

```
static_assert( sizeof(DataType1)==16, "Structure changed. Update serialize method" );
```

You have to set the size of the structure (the number in the check) per platform (or just for one platform).

Answer (score 0):

You can just add static variable "version" to your structures and increase it when structure changed.

```
static int version = 1234;
```

Then in your tests just write

```
static_assert( DataType1::version == HARD_CODE_VALUE );
```

But you still can forget to update version when change structure, or forget add some of new members when will update test.

Answer (score 0):

A craay method is to not use members directly.

Create an aggregate variardic template.  Create a data member template.

The data member template takes a tag struct.

Override `data_member<tag,T>::operator^( tag )` to return a reference to `T`.  Mqybe do the same for the free `operator^( data_member< tag, T >*, tag )`

Now you can get the member via `this^tag()`, which looks like member access.  If you make a global instance of `tag` you can even remove the `()`.

You also have compile time reflection on your data members,   So you can write `for_each_member`, and write all your serialization code once and use it for each `struct`.

Access control and other categories of `data_member` can be done in the `aggregate` template.

Tag based construction of data can be done with a complex and fancy `aggregate` constructor.

Alternatively you can wait for real reflection to show up in C++, probably within the decade.

Alternatively you can turn your `struct` into a `tuple` wrapper, and use something like the above override trick to get `this^tag` to work for name based access.

If we have a `struct foo` containing `int x, y` and `double d` we want to do this to, we might do the following:

```
// boilerplate
template<typename C, std::size_t idx> struct Tag {};
template<typename C, std::size_t tag_idx>
auto operator^(C&& lhs, Tag<C, tag_idx> const&>)
  -> decltype( std::get<tag_idx>( std::forward<C>(lhs) )
{ return std::get<tag_idx>( std::forward<C>(lhs); }

struct foo:std::tuple< int, int, double > {};
Tag< foo, 0 > x; // another annoying part: need to manually number them
Tag< foo, 1 > y; // we can avoid this via an aggregate trick, but
Tag< foo, 2 > d; // even that isn't all that pretty
int main() {
  foo bar;
  bar^x = 7;
  bar^y = 3;
  bar^d = 3.14;
}
```

one (serious) issue is that two member variables in two different `struct`s share the same "namespace" and conflict if they have the same name.